# Ladder diagram summation in QED

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

Is it possible to sum all ladder diagrams for example multiple photon exchange between two charged fermions in QED? I can't find anything but i'm sure it was done, for example to threat bound state of positronium.

Comment: Fetter & Walecka explicitly consider summation of bubble and ladder diagrams, although it is in the context of a non-relativistic electron gas.

Answer (score 1):

The repeated summation of all ladder diagrams is called Bethe-Salpeter T-matrix equation, which is usually employed for bound state calculation. See wiki page here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe%E2%80%93Salpeter_equation